# java.awt.FileDialog prematurely resolves symbolic links

Tags: java, awt, symlink, filedialog

I am having trouble opening files using `java.awt.FileDialog` without symbolic links being automatically resolved. E.g. given

```
/my/folder/with/links
/my/folder/with/links/foo_link
```

And

```
/my/folder/with/originals
/my/folder/with/originals/foo
```

And there is a symbolic link from `foo` to `foo_link`. Now if I navigate to `/my/folder/with/links/` and select `foo_link` to open, then `getDirectory` returns `/my/folder/with/originals` and `getFile` returns `foo`. But I really need to have a **handle on the actually selected folder**. If I need to, I can resolve this stuff myself using `getCanonicalFile`...

This appears on **OS X**, so I don't know if this is a platform specific problem. I would like to **stick to `java.awt.FileDialog`** instead of `javax.swing.JFileChooser`, because the latter is really crappy on OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good alternative might be [Web Look and Feel](http://weblookandfeel.com/) (GPL) which has a pretty good extension of `JFileChooser`, e.g. you can easily type in paths, so this would be comfortable enough for me. One thing that would be missing from `FileDialog` is remembering the last five or so locations, so that will need to be implemented.